# Leaflet maxBounds unexpectedly fix map to center

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I try to limit moving map out of focus but the map is fixed to centre and can't be moved.

```
var mapSW = [1000, 0],
    mapNE = [1000, 0];

var map = L.map('map', {
    crs: L.CRS.Simple,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoom: 1,
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: 4
});

var bounds = [[-250,-500], [800,800]];
var image = L.imageOverlay('uqm_map_full.png', bounds).addTo(map);

map.fitBounds(bounds); 

map.setMaxBounds(new L.LatLngBounds(
    map.unproject(mapSW, map.getMaxZoom()),
    map.unproject(mapNE, map.getMaxZoom()),
));
```

If I enable **setmaxBounds()** map's background image fix to centre and can be moved elastically. Map move, until it is dragged, after drag end map back to its centre.

I tried to follow few examples but still no success.
Do you see where I make mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mapSW` and `mapNE` coordinates are identical, so the LatLngBounds that you can build out of them is of null area.

Furthermore, I am not sure why you carefully build `bounds` for your Image Overlay (`image`) and to have the `map` fit those bounds, then using complicated `unproject` with different coordinates to specify to `setMaxBounds`?

Live example using the same `bounds` for `setMaxBounds`, enabling navigation to the same bounds as the Image Overlay:

```js
var map = L.map('map', {
  crs: L.CRS.Simple,
  zoomControl: true,
  zoom: 1,
  minZoom: 0,
  maxZoom: 4
});

var bounds = [
  [-250, -500],
  [800, 800]
];
var image = L.imageOverlay('https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/0/0/0.png', bounds, {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

map.fitBounds(bounds);

/*map.setMaxBounds(new L.LatLngBounds(
  map.unproject(mapSW, map.getMaxZoom()),
  map.unproject(mapNE, map.getMaxZoom()),
));*/
map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 200px"></div>
```

If you wish to restrict user navigation to a different area than your `image`'s bounds, you can easily do so by building similar bounds, without having to resort to `unproject` at all:

```js
var map = L.map('map', {
  crs: L.CRS.Simple,
  zoomControl: true,
  zoom: 1,
  minZoom: 0,
  maxZoom: 4
});

var bounds = [
  [-250, -500],
  [800, 800]
];
var image = L.imageOverlay('https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/0/0/0.png', bounds, {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

map.fitBounds(bounds);

/*map.setMaxBounds(new L.LatLngBounds(
  map.unproject(mapSW, map.getMaxZoom()),
  map.unproject(mapNE, map.getMaxZoom()),
));*/
map.setMaxBounds([
  [-300, -600],
  [900, 900]
]);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 200px"></div>
```